Uncaught TypeError: function is not a function when calling a const function from child
I am facing a problem, I have a function defined as follows
const myFunction= () =>{
    alert("Hi there!!!!")
    console.log("From child")
}

And I wish to call it from a popup, but the instruction
window.parent.myFunction()

does not work; does anyone know how to call the function in the parent?
Current error:

Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.myFunction is not a function.

I hope to see the message contained in the alert

What if you define the function "traditionally" as function myFunction() {     alert("Hi there!!!!")     console.log("From child") }

Is this a new window or a custom dialog? If you do it as a custom dialog (i.e., a hidden element that is shown/hidden as needed), then you can just call the function as normal.

const does not create a property on the window object.

can you please share more details?

It's not super clear why you're using window.parent() — I'll assume that you have some type of popup window thing going on.
A const function isn't globally exposed, so you probably can't call it from another page. This is really a good thing for security reasons.
You can use postMessage instead (this is the best workaround I can think of). Add a listener for messages in your parent page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Parent Window</title>
  <script>
    // Define the function in the parent
    function myFunction() {
      alert("Hi there!!!!");
      console.log("From parent");
    }

    // Listen for messages from the popup
    window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
      // Ensure you receive the message only from the expected origin
      if (event.origin !== "http://example.com") return; /* Replace example.com with your website. If you don't want any restrictions, remove this line */

      // Check the message data and call the function
      if (event.data === "callParentFunction") {
        myFunction();
      }
    });

    function openPopup() {
      window.open('popup.html', 'popupWindow', 'width=400,height=400');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="openPopup()">Open Popup</button>
</body>
</html>

In your popup.html file, use postMessage with window.opener to call the main page's function:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Popup Window</title>
  <script>
    function callParentFunction() {
      // Send a message to the parent
      window.opener.postMessage("callParentFunction", "http://example.com"); /* If you want to remove restrictions here, replace the website link with an asterisk (*) */
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="callParentFunction()">Call Parent Function</button>
</body>
</html>

Solution codes here

I don't think you need to post an answer since the question is low quality and lacks enough details. I've voted to close the question.

"t's not super clear why you're using window.parent() — I'll assume that you have some type of popup window thing going on." <-- The OP says "And I wish to call it from a popup,...", so that seems pretty clear to me.
